# ps g command replacement

Tags: unix

I'm looking for a way to perform an operation that was deprecated in the ps command, specifically `ps g`.

Is there any way to perform this operation or perhaps an equivalent option?

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, appears 'g' is:

```
        g            really all, even group leaders (does nothing w/o SunOS settings)
```

http://ss64.com/bash/ps.html

What OS are you running?